# Dynamic @media print stylesheet editing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I tested this function and notice the print pages isn't changing at all based on the else statement.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
function handlePrint(event) {

        var id = 'report-display';

        var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
        paginateReport = $("#paginateCheckBox").prop("checked");
        if (!paginateReport) {
            //parent.document.getElementById("#pageBreaker").style.pageBreakAfter = "auto";


        }
        else
        {
            //parent.document.getElementById("#pageBreaker").style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
            $('head').append('<style type="text/css" media="print">.pageBreak {page-break-after: always;} .pageBreak:last-of-type{page-break-after: avoid;}}</style>');
        }
        var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
        ifWin.focus();
        ifWin.printPage();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` right before your closing `style` tag.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it still doesn't change

Comment: I have spent quite a bit of time fighting with page-break-* styles for printing. Your styles may actually be getting applied, but the browser doesn't like them or disregards them. I would try adding in a very noticeable style (like changing the something's color to purple) to make sure this is working.

Comment: If I wasn't using an aspx file and ascx file this would be easier

Comment: I meant do something silly like `$('head').append('<style type="text/css" media="print">body {color: purple;}</style>');` and print to see if the style is being applied.